# Подогнать значение md5

Tags: tex, файлы, md5

Подскажите, возможно ли текстовый файл *.tex подогнать под нужное значение md5.

Задумка такая, что в одном текстовом файле есть некоторый текст, который необходимо заменить,  а недостающие значения md5 заполнить любой информацией.

Comment: Разумными ресурсами нет.

Comment: @Etki, а неразумными это какими? ))

Comment: А что значит "а недостающие значения md5 заполнить любой информацией."? md5 переведет любую строку в 32-символьное представление, хоть сколько не хранила в себе изначально строка.

Comment: @legik2003 точно не скажу, но подозреваю, что кластер серверов на несколько дней. Неразумными, короче.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [MD5 and MD4 Collision Generators](http://www.bishopfox.com/resources/tools/other-free-tools/md4md5-collision-code/) average run time on P4 1.6ghz PC: 45 minutes
- [Здесь](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/) тоже много всего.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, впечатляет.

Answer (score 1):

Просто перебором. Но это как повезет. Может, за десять минут, а может, за какое то кол-во лет.

В целом, если память не изменяет, то это классический пример NP задачи. Если научитесь решать ее быстро - то это как минимум уважение среди математиков и криптоанализаторов, и работа в хорошей компании по безопасности (а может быть, и в хорошей тюрьме:), так как для многих это будут большие риски в бизнесе и даже потенциальная потеря денег).